# Gradle flavor based on other flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

Is it possible that a flavor is based on a other flavor?

For example
**build.gradle:**

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        flavorBase "main"
    }
    flavor2 {
        flavorBase "main"
    }
    flavor3 {
        flavorBase "main"
    }
    flavor4 {
        flavorBase "flavor3"
    }
    flavor5 {
        flavorBase "flavor3"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't do that directly... Could you describe a sample case of which data you would like to share between flavors?

Comment: example main contains no colors and all logic,
flavor1 has his own colors and has a custom functions, same as flavor2,
flavor3 contains the colors for flavor4 & flavor5,
flavor4 contains custom functions,
flavor5 contains custom functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and needed something like a base flavor and two inherited flavors from that.

The best solution I ended up with after a few hours of trying out a lot of things was:

1. Create your additional flavors (flavor 4 and 5) same as you did for 1 and 2.
2. Create folders for those and create a base folder for common code/ressources (e.g. named flavor 3; the same way as you would do for your other flavors).
3. Now define additional source sets for your child flavors

   ```
   flavor4 {
       res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor3/res', 'src/flavor4/res']
       java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor3/java', 'src/flavor4/java']
       resources.srcDirs = ['src/flavor3/java', 'src/flavor4/java']
   }
   flavor5 {
       res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor3/res', 'src/flavor5/res']
       java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor3/java', 'src/flavor5/java']
       resources.srcDirs = ['src/flavor3/java', 'src/flavor5/java']
   }
   ```

So in flavor3 (which is in that sense not a flavor but I keep the naming as it was) you can define common code and resources.
The only downside is, that its not possible do have the same class in the base folder and in the child folders.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Could not get unknown property 'res' for ProductFlavor_Decorated`

Comment: @You'reAGitForNotUsingGit I run into the same issue, seems like providing more root path to the property helps for me, but I'm not 100% sure if this is the correct approach and why the way from the answer fails (but I don't understand Groovy in the first place, I'm always lost in the gradle files):
`sourceSets.flavor5.res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor3/res', 'src/flavor5/res']` `sourceSets.flavor5.java.srcDirs = ['src/flavor3/java', 'src/flavor5/java']`, etc (similar for "resources")

Answer (score 1):

You could use flavor dimensions to group features. For example:

```
flavorDimensions "color", "function", "data"
productFlavors {

    color1 {
        flavorDimension "color"
        // Something
    }
    color2 {
        flavorDimension "color"
        // Something else
    }

    functions1 {
        flavorDimension "function"
        // Something
    }  
    functions2 {
        flavorDimension "function"
        // Something else
    }

    data1 {
        flavorDimension "data"
        // Something
    }  
    data2 {
        flavorDimension "data"
        // Something else
    }    
}
```

Then you can factorize your code using these dimension like that :
Color1Function2Data1 or Color2Function1Data1...

Comment: This makes it possible to put the functions from flavor4 on the colors of flavor1..